# LESS & Bootstrap : error evaluating function `darken`: color.toHSL is not a function in file

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gulp, less

I am working with MobileAngularUI framework.

When gulp task build my app, with LESS source files overriding some Bootstrap variables, I get a strange error:

```
Error evaluating function `darken`: color.toHSL is not a function in file /Users/fabio/mobileangularui/bower_components/bootstrap/less/variables.less line no. 382
```

In my LESS file I'm overriding some variables like this for example:

```
@brand-primary: #FF9900;
@my-navbar-link-color: #3399CC;

@navbar-default-color: @brand-primary;
@navbar-default-link-color: @my-navbar-link-color;
```

What's the problem, why I get this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is written in `variables.less` line no. 382

Comment: You need to show us how your `darken` function is written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `variables.less`, the `@navbar-default-brand-color` variable is used:

```
@navbar-default-brand-color: @navbar-default-link-color;
@navbar-default-brand-hover-color: darken(@navbar-default-brand-color, 10%);
```

The error you get is because the darken function (LESS native function) is not able to parse your `@my-navbar-link-color`, so check you have a valid color (in the snippet, it seems to be valid)